# What is a weak long in the stock market?

Tags: trading, financial-literacy, terminology

What is a weak long? I often hear the term 'shaking out the weak longs' which  I believe refers to the temporary drop of a stock that forces novice traders (like me) to sell in panic, driving prices down so that the pros can buy the stock at a cheaper price. So basically a weak long is any novice trader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/weaklongs.asp), weak longs

> Refers to the group of investors that holds a long position and is quick to exit that position at the first sign of weakness. This group of investors is generally looking to capture the potential upside in a given security, but is not willing to take much loss. These investors will quickly close their positions when a trade does not work in their favor.
>
> Weak longs are regarded as the opposite of true long-term investors because they are not willing to hold their positions through all types of fluctuations. **Weak longs are generally short-term traders who are looking for a quick profit.** When the situation is not looking good, they will close their positions and go looking for opportunities elsewhere.

A weak long is someone who exits their long position at the first sign of weakness. This does not necessarily mean that they're a novice trader; they may simply be a trader looking to profit in the short-term, and the short-term decline triggers their risk management strategy and indicates that they should exit the market.

Comment: Or when the stock has gone up a lot and an investor is now over exposed, but trying to leave it until the last minute to sell some of the stock.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a weak long? I often hear the term 'shaking out the weak longs' which I believe refers to the temporary drop of a stock that forces novice traders (like me) to sell in panic, driving prices down so that the pros can buy the stock at a cheaper price. So basically a weak long is any novice trader?

I think that is a good summary.  Additionally, I view weak longs (or weak shorts) as those who feel confident as long as things are going their way, but start to second guess their decision when the trade begins to move against them.

For example, if I bought gold thinking it would go to $5000 when it was trading at $1900 a couple years ago and now its trading at $1300 with the fed talking about ending QE.  Between the price action and the fundamentals for gold, I might be thinking I made a bad decision buying at $1900.  I might choose to sell at $1300 and take a loss.  I might be considered "a weak long" because I'm not strong in my resolve that gold is going to $5000.

Another example is Apple at $700.  I could have thought its going to $1000, but now that its at $450 and Jobs is gone and Samsung is taking market share, I might second guess my original assessment and sell at a loss.  I might be a weak long.  Then again, I might be sensible.  Only the future will reveal it.